# How to keep both multi-lingual data as well as tree structures versioned?

Tags: mysql, version-control, query-performance

I'm currently working on a tool to build and alter books and articles.

- a book contains articles and has a specific structure
- an article can occur multiple times in the same book
- it is multi-lingual, so each article can (but doesn't have to) have different languages. (if there isn't any data present for the chosen language, just displaying a notice or similar is fine)
- later on, new languages may be added
- the depth/nesting is dynamic (an article can have sub-articles)
- both the articles as well as the structure have to be versioned (I later on have to be able to restore specific states)

here is my current approach for the database:
[image: current database structure]

with this, I could grab the latest version of a book like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM books AS b
JOIN structure AS s ON s.book_fk = b.id
AND s.book_version_nr =
(
    SELECT MAX(s2.book_version_nr)
    FROM structure AS s2
    WHERE s2.book_fk = b.id
)
JOIN articles AS a ON a.id = s.article_fk
JOIN article_texts AS as ON as.article_fk = a.id
AND as.version_nr = s.article_version_nr
AND as.language_fk = 'languageIdFromScript'
WHERE b.id = 'bookIdFromScript'
ORDER BY s.position ASC
```

However, this would mean that:

- if i create a new version of an article, i have to update the most recent structure to reflect this (but that also means that I "lose" the version since the content is now changed)
- if I add, remove or move an article around, I have to create a whole new structure version for the slightest change (this would lead to massive amounts of data in the database really fast and potentially affect the queries time)

This approach doesn't seem to be what I really want, as it is not possible to have different versions of different languages of the same article referenced in a single book structure. Also, the subselect seems to heavily slow down the whole process.

Is there any way to represent this connection as well as prevent any down-sides performance-wise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following:  Have two tables for structure:  One for the `Current` structure; this is updated whenever a change occurs.  The other is the `History` of the structure.

When you make a change, copy the current structure from `Current` into `History`, then modify `Current`.

This will slow down Inserts and Updates, but simplify Selects.

Multiple rows in `History` will point to the same `Articles`, `Users`, etc.  But that is OK.